# use a select for navigation with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, select, mobile, jquery-mobile, menu

I'm currently using the obox mobile plugin for WordPress to create a 'mobile' version of the site but that is beside the point really it uses jQuery mobile as the base and i want to use a select element as the navigation so that the user gets the default OS popup where they can choose an option (such as on the iPhone where you get the section at the bottom of the screen) this works to a degree but it doesn't integrate with the jquery mobile ajax based navigation and instead just loads the page as normal - is there anyway to get it to behave as a normal link would so the user can select an option from the menu and it would then transition to the page like it would if the user had clicked on a link?

I've looked over this for ages now and just can't seem to figure out a way to implement it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change page on select change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748827/change-page-on-select-change)

Answer (score 1):

**You can specify a transition type when you call the `changePage` function :**

```
$(document).delegate("#select", "change", function(){
    $.mobile.changePage("#"+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,{
        transition: "slideup" //add your app's default transition here
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for that - this should work but it just loads the page as normal, outside the jquery mobile control - for some reason something seems to be hijacking selects - as even with no code selecting an option forces the page to load...

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it like this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/TrghW/1/

JS

```
$('.navigateToPage').change(function() {
    var page = $(this).val();
    $.mobile.changePage( "#"+page, { transition: "slideup"} );
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">        
        <label for="pages" class="select">Navigate to page:</label>
        <select name="pages" id="selectPages" class="navigateToPage">
           <option>Select a Page</option>
           <option value="page2">Page 2</option>
           <option value="page3">Page 3</option>
           <option value="page4">Page 4</option>
           <option value="page5">Page 5</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <span>This is the Home Page</span>     
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="content">        
        <label for="pages2" class="select">Navigate to page:</label>
        <select name="pages2" id="selectPages2" class="navigateToPage">
           <option>Select a Page</option>
           <option value="home">Home Page</option>
           <option value="page3">Page 3</option>
           <option value="page4">Page 4</option>
           <option value="page5">Page 5</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <span>This is Page 2</span>  
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="content">        
        <label for="pages3" class="select">Navigate to page:</label>
        <select name="pages3" id="selectPages3" class="navigateToPage">
           <option>Select a Page</option>
           <option value="home">Home Page</option>
           <option value="page2">Page 2</option>           
           <option value="page4">Page 4</option>
           <option value="page5">Page 5</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <span>This is Page 3</span>     
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page4">
    <div data-role="content">        
        <label for="pages4" class="select">Navigate to page:</label>
        <select name="pages4" id="selectPages4" class="navigateToPage">
           <option>Select a Page</option>
           <option value="home">Home Page</option>
           <option value="page2">Page 2</option>           
           <option value="page3">Page 3</option>
           <option value="page5">Page 5</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <span>This is Page 4</span>     
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page5">
    <div data-role="content">        
        <label for="pages5" class="select">Navigate to page:</label>
        <select name="pages5" id="selectPages5" class="navigateToPage">
           <option>Select a Page</option>
           <option value="home">Home Page</option>
           <option value="page2">Page 2</option>           
           <option value="page3">Page 3</option>
           <option value="page4">Page 4</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <span>This is Page 5</span>     
    </div>
</div>
```